# Converting string to javascript words

Tags: javascript

I am using this to find all elements inside some div:

```
var counts = {}
var element = 'div';
$('.workspace').find('*').each(function() {
    var tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
    counts[tag] = counts[tag] || 0;
    counts[tag] ++;
});
```

Now I am checking does element exist in counts:

```
if(el in counts)
```

And if it does I am need to get number of divs with:
`counts.div` but since div is `string in var element` I need to use `counts.element` and there I get `error undefined` because it can't find element its like I said `counts.'elements'`.

Basically when i use counts.div or counts.header etc I get number of how many divs are there inside some element. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you looking for `counts[element]`? <-- [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

Comment: @le_m take the 15 seconds to write the answer and you'll get my upvote

Comment: Oh my god I am brain dead! Make an answer I will upvote.

Comment: @JoeFrambach Ok ok, I posted it as an answer ;)

Comment: @NoNameIamLame Don't worry, we will revive you ;)

Comment: @le_m I was trying to do it in so harder way to find index and then by index number to get value lol :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `counts[element]`? This is called [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation). You already used it when accessing `counts[tag]++`.

Answer (score 1):

You are already using jQuery, use `jQuery()` , `.filter()`

```
var counts = $(".workspace *");
var element = "div";
var len = counts.filter(element).length;
```

Comment: Alternatively `$(element).is(counts)`